# Glossary threads

Tags: discussion

We've got two glossary-style threads going at the moment:

- **[Terminology Index](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/667#667)**
- **[What's your most useful cycle accessory?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/573/whats-your-most-useful-cycle-accessory)**

Both are potentially quite useful, particularly the Terminology Index, but there's already some overlap.

- It seems that we could spend a lot of time managing the two glossaries. Are they useful as separate entities as they are?
- How can we distinguish the two -- can we more clearly define what each glossary is and what the entries should look like?
- How can we get rid of overlap -- perhaps they should be merged?

**Edit**:

I'm also concerned with entries [like](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/573/whats-your-most-useful-cycle-accessory/586#586) [these](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/573/whats-your-most-useful-cycle-accessory/703#703) that are basically product recommendations, where other companies make the same thing.

Perhaps the terminology index could get into the history of the items more? The Presta/Schrader valves is a perfect example of this.

Comment: What's the harm in putting in products? If it's truly a good product it will be upvoted otherwise it won't be.

Comment: @Joe: Because the structure of this site really isn't a fit for these kind of threads; it's unclear if an upvote is for the product or the recommendation.

Answer (score 4):

I vote for keeping them separate entities.

If I want to know what something was I would check the terminology index, but I see the cycle accessory thread as a "what's a cool/handy thing to have". I've already ordered a couple of items that were mentioned in the accessory thread :)

Comment: Agreed.  In particular, one is defining *what* things are, while the other describes *why* you might want that thing.

Answer (score 1):

I put some notes about this in the threads, in the main question areas. Did I interpret this correctly? I tried to keep it brief.

Answer (score 1):

I'll echo the concern about specific products.  The two you mention in particular ([Garmin Forerunner](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/573/whats-your-most-useful-cycle-accessory/586#586), [Light & Motion Seca](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/573/whats-your-most-useful-cycle-accessory/703#703)) are not particularly unique so those entries would be better termed "a GPS cyclocomputer" and "a good bicycle headlight" rather than being specific products.

Comment: They may not be unique but they are some of the best products in that category which I find to be a lot more useful than putting generic things in there. For instance, it's not the GPS feature that makes the Garmin so useful -- it's a lot of the smaller usability things. The fact you can wear it on your wrist. Stuff like that separates the products

Comment: @Joe Phillips: personally I'd rather see the general category ("good bicycle headlight") at the top of the answer, followed by a description of what makes a good headlight, with the specific model you like more towards the end...

Comment: @freiheit: I agree with you about making these more general -- perhaps use something more specific than "good bicycle headlight", maybe "rechargable LED headlight" or something like that? Perhaps that stuff belongs on a companion wiki.

Comment: "rechargeable hi-lumen LED headlight with a good pattern"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they should exist at all. This is supposed to be a Q&A site. How can you answer the question "Terminology Index"?